# Android: Encrypt multiple files in one file and decrypt one of them

Tags: android, encryption

I encrypted multiple files in one file in order.
Now I want to decrypt only one of those files. for this purpose I did this:
I got all bytes of encrypted files as array Like this: (first index: byte offset of every file in the encrypted file, second index: length of file bytes in the encrypted file)

```
int[] file1 = new int[] {0 ,109624}
int[] file2 = new int[] {109624,40480}
int[] file3 = new int[] {150104,153640}
int[] file4 = new int[] {303744,24320}
```

Now for getting specific file from the encrypted file and decrypt it I should to read the encrypted file. First of all, skip the bytes of previous files.
for skipping them I use this method (for example I want to encrypt file2):

```
int fromByte = file2[0];
int fileLength = file2[1];
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(fis,cipher);
long skipBytes = cis.skip(fromByte);
```

Then it reads byte to byte of source file in "while" loop and when length of read file bytes equals to `fileLength`, it breaks loop.

I brought all the codes at the end here.

When I decrypt first file (from byte:0 and file length:109624 and it dosn't need to "skip bytes"), It works well.
But when I decrypt other files (for example for encrypt file2 it needs to skipt 109624 byte from source file), It doesn't work well and created file is not decrypted.

Why it dosn't work for other files?

Here's my codes:

```
public void decryptFile(File sourceFile, File targetFile, int fromByte, int lengthToRead, SecretKeySpec keySpec) {
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(targetFile);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE,keySpec);
        CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(fis,cipher);
        int readPart,currentLength = 0, bufferSize = 8;
        long skipBytes;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[bufferSize];
        skipBytes = cis.skip(fromByte);
        while ((readPart = cis.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            fos.write(bytes,0,readPart);
            currentLength += bufferSize;
            if (currentLength >= lengthToRead) {
                break;
            }
        }
        cis.close();
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Here's My codes for encrypt multiple files in on file:

```
public void encryptFile(File[] sourceFiles, File targetFile, SecretKeySpec keySpec) {
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(targetFile);
        FileInputStream fis;
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,keySpec);
        CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(fos,cipher);
        int readPart,bufferSize = 8;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[bufferSize];
        for (File sourceFile : sourceFiles) {
            fis = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
            while ((readPart = fis.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                cos.write(bytes, 0, readPart);
            }
            fis.close();
        }
        cos.flush();
        cos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: `currentLength += bufferSize;` That should be `currentLength += readPart;`

Comment: Thank you @blackapps . I test it but there is no difference between both method. as I said, It works for first file but doesn't work for other files

Comment: `long skipBytes = cis.skip(fromByte);` Please tell the value of skipBytes for fromByte 0 and 109624.

Comment: What is the file size of the second target file ? Compare to original.

Comment: `bufferSize = 8;` That is small. Why not 8192?

Comment: skipBytes = 8176; 
second target file length = 40480; and original = 40474

Comment: I asked two values for skipBytes.

Comment: if fromByte==0 , skipBytes=0;  if fromByte==109624, skipBytes=8176

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218871/discussion-between-m-feyz-and-blackapps).

Comment: What does 8176 mean?

Comment: I don't know, it's surprising @blackapps

Comment: I suggest to do a test where you put four times the same file in one file.

Comment: Another possibility is to read the bytestobeskipped from the InputStream. After that open the CipherInputStream on the -resulting- inputstream. So skip the bytes yourself.

Comment: I edit my question and add my codes for encrypt multiple file. @blackapps

Comment: I test encrypt same file four times (instead of four file) in one file and get these results: file size was 40474 and it's encrypted size was 40480. add this file two times, it's encrypted file size was: 80960. add three times, it's size was: 121432 (instead of 121440 . it's 8 byte less than 121440). add four times, it's size was: 161904 (instead of 161920 . it's 16 bytes less than 161920) @blackapps

Comment: That is pretty strange. You have a buffer of 8 bytes. Make it 8192 for a test.

Comment: I think the cipher combines the last bytes of the first file with the first bytes of the second file. How many bits are used to encrypt? File size should be a multiple otherwise padding occurs. Something like that.

Comment: How did you determine those values for file1, file2,..? There is nothing in your encrypting code that determines them.

Comment: When I encrypt the files I get created bytes size and save them in an array @blackapps

Comment: Please show complete code. How can we help if not?

Comment: I discovered that the problem is the difference between bytes of original file and encrypted file. When we encrypt the file, it's length changes to be multiple of 8 or 16 or .... If original file length is a multiple of 8, It works well. but how can I fix the difference? @blackapps

Comment: At the end of encrypting a file write the missing bytes to output. Try with spaces. Just pad yourself.

Comment: Thank you @blackapps for your supports. as I said the problem is difference between original file length and encrypted file length to be multiple of 8. also other problem is in skip method. I fix codes and answer to my question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized the problem, After many reviews.

There are two problem in this codes:

problem 1: in skip method. we should check the `skipBytes` and if it is not equal to `fromByte`, it must repeat. for this purpose add these codes:

```
while (skipBytes<fromByte) {
    fromByte -= skipBytes;
    skipBytes = cis.skip(fromByte);
}
```

problem 2: in encrypt function. if the file length is not multiple of 8, encryption method add some bytes until its length is multiple of 8. for fix this problem we should to add those bytes to the file ourselves before encrypt it. for this purpose add these codes before encrypt every file:

```
int remaining = (int) (sourceFile.length() % 8);
if (remaining>0) {
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(sourceFile,true));
    while (remaining<8) {
        bw.write(" ");
        remaining++;
    }
    bw.close();
}
```

This codes modifies source file. If you want to don't modifying source file, instead of above codes, use this codes after ending encryption while loop:

```
int remainder = (int)(sourceFile.length() % 8);
if (remainder>0) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
    while (remainder<8) {
        sb.append(" ");
        remainder++;
    }
    byte[] additionBytes = sb.toString().getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    cos.write(additionBytes, 0, additionBytes.length);
}
```

Comment: So you are modifying the source files. That is not a good idea. I had suggested adding the missing bytes while encrypting.

Comment: How can I add the bytes to encryption without add them to source files? @blackapps

Comment: Like you have cos.write(bytes,0,readPart); you can at end of file `bytes[0]=' ';` and use `cos.write(bytes, 0, 1);` as many times as you want.

Comment: Thank you so much @blackapps . I edit my codes and add to my answer.